# jQuery or Javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-effects

I'm just beginning learning javascript and jQuery and need some help. I am trying to get a picture to start at the bottom of the page (of the viewers window) and animate or slide (or any other effect - I am not too knowledgable at this point) diagonally across the page to the top...

The example is a spider diagonally going to the top of the page. Any idea of what type of javascript/jQuery function I can use. Any help would be super appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript, but it's a library to make coding easier.

Comment: if you animate a div, look this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Comment: yes I know, thank you! But I was not sure if there was a jQuery function made for this type of effect I am looking for or if I had to build a javascript function myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [`animate` function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Could be as simple as:

```
$('img').animate({'left': '+=500px', 'top': '-=500px'});
```